# PHP won't insert into the database in PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, file-upload, insert, phpmyadmin

So I've been battling with this for days trying to figure out why my 'products' are not uploading into phpMyAdmin after the user submits a form - The application is one that allows members to create their own products...& the place i'm stuck at is as follows: I'm a logged in user i'm on the "List a Product" page from my user admin.  when i enter the product info then click to submit it won't post the product & associated data to phpmyadmin.  and I'm trying to move the image uploaded to a folder via a move_uploaded_file function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  All code should be below (database is connected and all the sessions set properly, etc I believe):

Form from the create_product.php (the page where a logged in user lists a new product:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_name'], $_POST['product_description'])) {
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_description = $_POST['product_description'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($product_name) || empty($product_description)) {
    $errors[] = "All Fields are required";
} else {
    if (strlen($product_name) > 55 || strlen($product_description) > 255) {
        $errors[] = "One or more fields contains too many characters";
    } 

}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, '<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        create_product($product_name, $product_description);

        header("location: product.php?product_id='.$product_id.'");
        exit();
    }
}

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Product Name:<br/><input type="text" name="product_name" maxlength="55" /></p>
        <p>Describe this Product:<br/><textarea name="product_description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="255"></textarea></p>

        <p>Upload a product profile pic:<br/><input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create"></p>
    </form>
```

Function from my product.functions.php file (which is included on the create_product.php file):

```
function create_product($product_name, $product_description) {
$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($product_name));
$product_description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($product_description));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['member_id']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$product_name', '$product_description')");

$bmid = mysql_insert_id();
// place image in the folder
$newname = "$bmid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],'uploads/$newname');
}
```

I believe my issue may be coming from the image upload, but i've been struggling with this forever...Thanks for any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few issues with this. First is the insert statement. You do not need the `, that is MySQL specific and not required. Second you have a null value for what might be your ID field. change your insert statement to be (of course with your column names):

```
 INSERT INTO products (member,date_time,prod_name,prod_desc) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['member_id']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$product_name', '$product_description')
```

That woud cause your file not to upload and the database not to be updated. The other thing that you can try and can cause some issues is removing the php variables from the string and concating them together. The newname variable should be written as.

```
$location = "uploads/" . $bmid . ".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],$location);
```

If this does not work then you will need to output the SQL and any error that it is throughing.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO products (member,date_time,prod_name,prod_desc) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['member_id']."', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '".$product_name."', '".$product_description".')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
if(!$result) echo "SQL: ", $SQL, "<br />ERROR: ", mysql_error();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James (& other responders), so the INSERT INTO () VALUES () fix worked and I've got products loading into phpMyAdmin...and the image did actually load into the uploads folder but its not showing up as "product_id#.jpg" like it should be.  It just shows up as "$newname" (I thought the variable would have worked there and picked up the product id (which should be the $bmid after i used $bmid = mysql_insert_id();

Comment: you have to remove $bmid from the qoutes and concat the .jpg on the end like above.

Comment: sorry - forgot to mention that...i did do that as you instructed as well & still didn't show up - just showed up as "$newname" in the folder.

Comment: got it...minor mistake on my part.  you da man - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `INSERT` query, you forgot to put the column/s names before the `VALUES()` it should be `INSERT INTO table_name (columns_name) VALUES (values);`